# MKV videos not working on smart tv web app

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming, tizen-web-app, webos

I am creating a streaming application, where user can access a list of mkv files from my server, Mkv is not supported in web browsers and it is not loading properly within my smart tv web app.

I cannot modify my files to another video format.

Is there a native player for those smart TVs that I can embed into my web application ?

Is there any video player with web sdk to play mkv on a smart tv.

Ps: my videos are working well on chrome, as for Firefox or Safari, it tells me that the format is not supported.

Smart TVs : LG webOS, Tizen (Samsung)

Comment: From 2021 Samsung TV Spec, mkv video is supported. https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/specifications/media-specifications/2021-tv-video-specifications.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment, any idea about how to make it possible on LG devices ?